# radgrid dynamic columns with filtertemplate

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

telerik grid is build after other grid get clicked.
i wnat to create grid2 columns with `AutoGenerateColumns="True"` .

after grid1 got clicked there is postback and im getting the value of grid1
so i can get more data to bind grid2.

```
protected void grid1_ItemCommand(object sender, GridCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "RowClick")
        {
            tableID = Convert.ToInt32(((GridDataItem)e.Item).GetDataKeyValue("Id"));

            grid2.Rebind();

        }
    }
```

after clicked i set datasource of grid2:

```
protected void grid2_NeedDataSource(object sender, GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e)
    {
        grid2.DataSource = data;
        grid2.Visible = data.Count > 0;
    }
```

how can i set the Templatefilter for some columns?

Comment: If I understand correctly you would like to create a filter for an auto generated column at run time. Correct?

Comment: yes , after postback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after some testing and research i saw this [telerik post](http://www.telerik.com/forums/filtering-on-a-command-column)

that my working code:

```
protected void grid2_ColumnCreated(object sender, GridColumnCreatedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Column.UniqueName == "Description")
        {
            GridBoundColumn bCol = e.Column as GridBoundColumn;
            if (bCol != null)
            {
                TemplateAutoCompleteFilter template = new TemplateAutoCompleteFilter(
                                   RadComboBoxFilter.Contains, data.Select(r => r.Name).ToArray());
                bCol.FilterTemplate = template;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to set your filter in code behind using _prerender.
Here there is an example I found where you have obviously to customize your filter according to your needs:

```
protected void RadGrid1_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       //if (!Page.IsPostBack)
       //{
           RadGrid1.MasterTableView.FilterExpression = "([Country] LIKE \'%UK%\') ";
           GridColumn column = RadGrid1.MasterTableView.GetColumnSafe("Country");
           column.CurrentFilterFunction = GridKnownFunction.StartsWith;
           column.CurrentFilterValue = "UK";
           RadGrid1.MasterTableView.Rebind();
       //}
   }
```

Try and would be nice to know if it works for you.

**Update**
post back commented out

Comment: i dont have problem with create expression , i want user to select country from list, how do i create this list and attach it to the column?

Comment: This is a completely different question! Lets start fixing the above. Did it work?

Comment: However, if the user has to select a country, would be practical to use a drop down column and bind it to a db table with all the countries listed. then use the selected value to do what you need. Something like this http://it.tinypic.com/r/30m0m5c/8

Comment: you suggest to take the filter out of the grid? i realy want the filter to be on top of the specifc column